# The array $form_state undefined with ajax

Tags: ajax, forms

Why when I submit form generated with ajax, the array $form_state is undefined?

this is a part of module:

1)

```
$form['#tree'] = TRUE;

$form['addTel'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Add'),
        '#submit' => array(
            'call_tel'
        ),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'call_addTel',
            'wrapper' => 'my_wrapper'
        ),
    );
```

2)

```
//call_tel ajax
function call_tel($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['telefono'];
}
//callback
function call_addTel($form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['i']['tel']++;
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

3)

```
//this is a form generated
$form['tel']['my-tel']   = array(
                '#title' => t('Telefono'),
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#markup' => '',
                '#id' => 'campo-telefono[]'
            );
```

Why I call `$form_state['values']['tel']['my-tel']['#value']` after submit it is undefined?

Comment: Hi! Can you please provide a better explanation and code sample like how you're adding the dynamic fields or are you just updating a field value using ajax. like how are you using $form_state['i']['tel'] and $form['telefono']. Thanks